# Is this x in local scope of inner function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

Consider the following code, I expected the output to be 2 since the `x` to be printed is a local variable in the scope of `inner` function. However, it printed `2` instead. I don't understand why that is the case. Any explanation and/or comment is appreciated.

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        x = 1
        x += 1
        print x
    return x
```

Comment: You expected 2 and it printed 2 instead? Isn't that the same? Also, that code doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate `x` variables here: the `outer` function has an `x` variable and the `inner` function has its own `x` variable.

From the moment there is an assignment to a variable somewhere in a function, the variable has a local scope.

So when you call `outer()`, you will return `1`. The `x` in the `inner` function is a different one, and furthermore `inner()` is *never* called. As a result, the (local) `x` is not printed.

If you thus would have written:

```
def outer():
    x = 3
    def inner():
        x = 1
        x += 1
        print x
    return x
```

Then calling `outer()` will return `3`. Even if you would have called `inner()` in the `outer()` function, it would **not make any difference**. Since the `x` in the `inner()` function is another one than the one in the `outer()` function (there is a local scope defined in `inner`). Although it would mean that you `print 2`, you will `return 3`.

Comment: Thank you Willem, for pointing it out! It seems that my understanding about scope is correct, but I never call `inner` function inside `outer`.

Comment: @RuilinLi: well the two `x` variables act independently.